# How do I search data in from datatable based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have created one datatable:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string))
dt.Columns.Add("place", typeof(string))
dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string))
dt.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string))
```

and I have inserted some data in this datatable:

```
DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();    // Create New Row
dtrow["Country"] = "India";            //Bind Data to Columns
dtrow["place"] = "wizag";
dtrow["Price"] = "7520";
dtrow["Desc"] = "Anywhere";
dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

dtrow = dt.NewRow();               // Create New Row
dtrow["Country"] = "India";               //Bind Data to Columns
dtrow["place"] = "Goa";
dtrow["price"] = "4500";
dtrow["Desc"] = "Anything";
dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
```

I have bind this datatable with my grid view. I have also added one textbox and one search button in mmy aspx page. My requirement is that I want to search data based on user input e.g like 4500 or wizag, and if country name is the same I want to show it in one row

How can I do this?

Comment: try https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322 or get a nice book on asp.net

Comment: If you show us what you've tried, and describe the problems you've had, you are much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sir only i want to search  datatable as input provided by the user it may be any country name or price or place ...............................

Comment: @abhinaykumar did my approach help you solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `DataView` in this case

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "price = 4500 AND Country = 'India'"; 
GridView.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
GridView.DataBind();
```